# set figure size (mpl) is not influence canvas and layout

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, pyqt4

I'm trying to adjust widget size to figure size. For some reason the size of the canvas and the widget is not changing. I tried to set SizePolicy of the container widget and the canvas, same result.

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class CanvasOnWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self._layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self._fig = plt.figure()
        self._layout.addWidget(self._fig.canvas)
        plt.plot(range(10),range(10))
        self._fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self._resize)

    def _resize(self, event):
        w,h = self._fig.get_size_inches()
        if event.button == 1: # left click
            h-=1
        elif event.button == 3: # right click
            h+=1
        self._fig.set_size_inches(w, h, forward=True)
        self._fig.canvas.draw()
        self._fig.canvas.flush_events()
        print self.size()
        print self._fig.canvas.size()
        print self._fig.get_size_inches()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = CanvasOnWidget()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to inform the widget about your desire to change its size. 
This can be done using `.resize`. Due to there being a border around the canvas you need to take this border into account when setting the new widget size.

```
import sys
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class CanvasOnWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self._layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self._layout)
        self._fig = Figure()
        self.canv = FigureCanvas(self._fig)
        self._layout.addWidget(self.canv)

        ax = self._fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(range(10),range(10))
        self._fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self._resize)

    def _resize(self, event):
        w,h = self._fig.get_size_inches()
        dw = self.size().width()-w*self._fig.dpi
        dh = self.size().height()-h*self._fig.dpi
        if event.button == 1: # left click
            h-=1
        elif event.button == 3: # right click
            h+=1
        self._fig.set_size_inches(w, h, forward=True)

        self._fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        self.resize(w*100+dw,h*100+dh)

        print self.size()
        print self._fig.canvas.size()
        print self._fig.get_size_inches()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = CanvasOnWidget()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that I have changed to code in order to place a `Figure` into a  `FigureCanvasQT`. Using pyplot inside a Qt GUI will lead to problems.

However, if you want to use pyplot, the whole code can be simplified a lot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Plot():

    def __init__(self):
        self._fig = plt.figure()
        ax = self._fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(range(10),range(10))
        self._fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self._resize)

    def _resize(self, event):
        w,h = self._fig.get_size_inches()
        if event.button == 1: # left click
            h-=1
        elif event.button == 3: # right click
            h+=1
        self._fig.set_size_inches(w, h, forward=True)

        self._fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        print self._fig.get_size_inches()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Plot()
    plt.show()
```